# Telerik and ASP.NET controls are not working with Safari

Tags: asp.net, safari, telerik

I am using telerik AJAX controls and Microsoft ASP.NET Controls. Controls are compatible with IE, FireFox, Chrome but not working in Safari.
I have tried to use menu control, button, combobox, grids of Telerik and microsoft builting controls but server side events are not working on Safari.
I found some links which are saying that they got solution, I tried them but they are of no use. here are the links

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/429169/ASP-NET-menu-control-issue-in-Chrome-and-Safari

http://bettereducation.com.au/it/yaf_postsm2938_Problem-with-rendering-aspnet-menu-control-in-Chrome-and-Safari.aspx

solution mention in above links are not working. Please help me out in this regard and please provide some test project which having mentioned controls and is working on Safari.

Regards
Sheeraz Raza

Comment: do you have an error message, or just controls doesn't appears ?